# XPath to get specific element

Tags: scala, selenium, xpath

I have to find two input fields (username and password) to use it in Selenium 
I'm using xpath, but I can't able to get this elements and app throws this exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find the User Name input field
>   defined by xpath locator.

Have Following HTML structure :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to handle elements inside an `iframe` you should switch to it first.

I'm not sure about correctness of this `Scala` code, but according to [this](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium) it should be something like below:

```
switch to frame("injectedUI")
textField("email").value = "Username"
```

Comment: I'm using this structure:                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                             
val element: WebElement = driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("injectedUl"))).findElement(By.xpath(xpath));                                                                                            xpath is: this string: val username : String = "//input[@id='email']"                    but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean *doesn't work*? Can you share exception log? Also note that there are to `input` fields with `id="email"`: one is inside an `iframe` and another- outside. Check that you're trying to handle proper one

Comment: there was another error, your advice was perfect ;). Thank you again.